# Change the font color of generated word cloud

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am currently using [this library](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) to generate a word cloud. Currently, the generated picture looks like this:
[image: Word Cloud Generated]

However, I will only be able to print this out using the black-white printer, therefore the font color will be to shallow and I want to change them into black. Unfortunately, [this](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/a_new_hope.py) is the only example that I can found, where the code reads:

```
def grey_color_func(word, font_size, position, orientation, random_state=None,**kwargs):
    return "hsl(0, 0%%, %d%%)" % random.randint(60, 100)
wc = WordCloud(max_words=1000, mask=mask, stopwords=stopwords, margin=10,random_state=1).generate(text)
# store default colored image
default_colors = wc.to_array()
plt.title("Custom colors")
plt.imshow(wc.recolor(color_func=grey_color_func, random_state=3),
interpolation="bilinear")
```

I have no idea what does `grey_color_func` do in this case, or how to change it to generate a black color.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Are you aware of what HSL is and how it differs from RGB or hex?

Comment: See the `color_func` parameter on line 220 in the [source code](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/wordcloud/wordcloud.py#L150) of the docstring for  `class WordCloud`.

Comment: Nope. That is the question. What is hsl exactly?

Answer (score 0):

This has a lot to do with what [HSL(A)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) represent on this scale.  Since both hue and saturation are set to zero, the luminosity is what is controlling the gray scale portion.  That is, this particular random value is determining the gray scale:

```
random.randint(60, 100)
```

Practically, you need to change the bounds of this random int to a value between 0 and 30, or between 0 and [whatever value you feel is appropriately "dark" enough](http://hslpicker.com/#595959) to work with your printer.

Comment: Thanks. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

HSL means Hue-saturation-lightness ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)). You can also change the h (i.e. hue) value in the string returned to get different colors:

```
def grey_color_func(word, font_size, position, orientation, random_state=None,
                    **kwargs):
    return "hsl(203, 100%%, %50d%%)" % random.randint(60, 100)  
# hsla(282, 100%, 50%, 1) PINK
# hsla(203, 100%, 50%, 1) BLUE
```

which is fun. I used [this](https://hslpicker.com/#009dff) site to get the hsla color values, (and I then just ignored the a (i.e. alpha) value).

Also that strange bit of syntax at the bottom: `"hsl(203, 100%%, %50d%%)" % random.randint(60, 100)`, is some c-style [string formatting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm). What's returned by the randint() call goes into the string at the %d (or %50d as in my code. I'm not sure exactly why/how but playing around with that prepended number changes the colors a little).